# Eclipse rendering problems

Tags: java, eclipse, rendering

Eclipse Kepler sometimes fails to update regions of the screen, ie. when tooltips get removed there is a black box remaining, ie. parts of the editor etc. does not get redrawn.

Is there anything I can do about that?

Using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS amd64 and the included openjdk 7.

Answer (score 2):

Had similar issues with eclipse luna on debian wheezy with oracle JDK7. Understand these are issues with GTK3. Resolved by exporting SWT_GTK3=0 before running eclipse. Via a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
/path_to_eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: This should be an approved answer, thanks a lot.
It helps to fix rendering problems for i3wm as well.