# Eclipse (Luna) shows blank widgets throughout

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora, kde-plasma

I'm running the latest Eclipse (Luna, CDT edition) and am having a strange problem where many widgets throughout various menus are blank.  I have tried updating from an earlier version of eclipse, downloading a fresh version, and using new user accounts with empty workspaces, but nothing seems to populate these windows.  See below for an example of one such blank window.

Could there be a missing library that is needed to update these widgets?  No errors appear on the command line when starting eclipse.

OS: Fedora 19, KDE 4.11.5
Java: 1.8.0_25
Eclipse Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
Eclipse Build id: 20140925-1800

Example blank window:
[image: Blank Eclipse Installation Details window]

Comment: Change theme and check.Change theme here `Windows > Preferences > General > Appearance`

Comment: I tried changing to a few different themes, but the problem remains

Comment: Try to resize the window. Does that help?

Comment: Also try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20283035/rendering-of-buttons-with-images-in-eclipse-kepler-is-broken/27292432#27292432

Comment: @AaronDigulla resizing the window did not work.  And neither did specifying: GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The fix for the tab height issue helps since its a [GTK2 vs GTK3 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735527/eclipse-rendering-problems).

If you have an ***eclipse.desktop*** file you could start eclipse as:

```
Exec=env SWT_GTK3=0 /path_to_eclipse/eclipse
```

or use:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SWT_GTK3=0
/path_to_eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: I tried this, but this option results in some sort of java failure: java: /builddir/build/BUILD/oxygen-gtk2-1.4.5/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion `!_button._widget' failed.

Comment: I got this to work after also applying the fix mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26590329/804775  Thanks for the help!